# How can I be alerted for security breach, bulletin, CVE for a list of manufacturers

Tags: cve

I'm trying to find a solution to be able to be alerted of security alerts for a list of software, hardware that we are using.

I've found https://www.secalerts.co, which looks good, but it seems that sometimes the alert comes a bit late. I've received an alert yesterday for something that was already patched by the dev more than 10 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually follow the official MITTRE CVE account feed : https://twitter.com/CVEnew